# Initialize virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, virtual-attribute

I have an `IncomingEmail` model with an `attachments` virtual attribute:

```
class IncomingEmail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :attachments
end
```

I want the `attachments` virtual attribute to be initialized to `[]` rather than `nil` so that I can do:

```
>> i = IncomingEmail.new
=> #<IncomingEmail id: nil,...)
>> i.attachments << "whatever"
```

Without first setting `i.attachments` to `[]` (put another way, I want this virtual attribute to default to an empty array rather than `nil`)

Answer (score 3):

use `after_initialize` callback

```
class IncomingEmail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :attachments
  def after_initialize
    self.attachments ||= [] # just in case the :attachments were passed to .new
  end
end
```